# How to have a Non-English namespace in mediawiki?

Tags: php, namespaces, mediawiki

I created a custom namespace in my mediawiki as below following this doc: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual_talk:Using_custom_namespaces

I created a namespace as bellow:

```
define("NS_CAFE", 3000); // This MUST be even.
define("NS_CAFE_TALK", 3001); // This MUST be the following odd integer.
$wgExtraNamespaces[NS_CAFE] = "کافه";
$wgExtraNamespaces[NS_CAFE_TALK] = "کافه_بحث"; // Note underscores in the namespace name.
$wgNamespaceProtection[NS_CAFE] = array( 'editfoo' ); // permission "editfoo" required to edit the foo namespace
$wgNamespacesWithSubpages[NS_CAFE] = true;            // subpages enabled for the foo namespace
$wgGroupPermissions['sysop']['editfoo'] = true;      // permission "editfoo" granted to users in the "sysop" group
$wgContentNamespaces[] = NS_CAFE;
```

AS NS_CAFE is in our language then what values should be for `$wgNamespaceProtection[NS_CAFE]` and for second array element of `$wgGroupPermissions['sysop']` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permission names are seldom seen by users (except on *Special:ListGroupRights*). They face the consequences of being granted or denied certain rights. Therefore, there is no point in choosing non-Latin names for user rights, and your `editfoo` is all right.

However, you need to create two *MediaWiki* messages in your wiki:

- `MediaWiki:right-editfoo`, which will be seen on *Special:ListGroupRights* and
- `MediaWiki:action-editfoo`, which will be used in a sentence like "You do not have permission to (editfoo)".

It makes sense to create those messages in your wiki language, e.g. *ویرایش کافه*. If you expect some users to change their user interface language to some other language, you may want to define versions of those messages in that language, too: e.g., `MediaWiki:right-editfoo/en` and `MediaWiki:right-editfoo/en`.